# Unable to limit Apache server-status page to localhost

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, apache2

I am using Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu.

I want to allow reading server status only from localhost.

In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf` I have:

```
<Location /server-status>
          SetHandler server-status
          Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

I have read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html and and from I belive the above configuration should be working. I have restarted Apache to ensure that new configuration is active. However the status page is still open for reading from anywhere.

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf` I have:

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www
 <Location />
        Require all granted
 </Location>
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i can see, the virtual host config file seems to take precedence over the `mod_status` config file.

Actually you grant all to `/` within `mysite.conf` :

```
<Location />
        Require all granted
</Location>
```

This results in that everyone can access `/server-status`.

You would have to manage permissions to `/server-status` in the virtual host config file itself `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/status.conf` :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
 <Location />
        Require all granted
 </Location>
 <Location /server-status>
        Require local
 </Location>
```

From there, whatever permissions you set in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf` they will be ignored as `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/status.conf` takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below location directive in the status.conf

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

After this install lynx in your machine from CLI. Lynx is a fully-featured World Wide Web (WWW) client for users which can be accessed over Linux terminals.

For Ubuntu, Install lynx using

```
 apt-get install lynx
```

Run the below command to check apache server status

```
 lynx http://localhost/server-status
```

Comment: The docs say for 2.4 say: `The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.` I would prefer to use other solution, if there is one.